# Преобразование числа в строку(Javascript)

Tags: javascript

У меня есть число `1.234567890e+9`.
А нужно получить строку `'1234567890'`.

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Возможно вам помогут библиотеки работы с большими числами (Bignumber)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1685917/4177355

Answer (score 4):

```js
var x = 1.234567890e+9;
console.log(x.toFixed());
```

Comment: если e = 30 или больше то такие же действия?

Comment: @ПавелЮхневич, упс...

Answer (score 0):

Что-то типо.

```js
alert(1.234567890e+30.toFixed().split("e")[0].replace(".", ""))
```

Comment: Получается 123456789, вместо 1234567890

Comment: `1.234567890e+30` = `1234567890000000000000000000000` если что...